# Do Apple Apps run with higher privilege on Mac

Tags: macos, mac

Its a silly question but I wouldn't be surprised if Apple did this on purpose.
Do their Apps run with higher privilege (hidden) than other 3'th party Apps do?
I recently switched from Apple Music to Spotify and sometimes, when my machine is under heavy load, the music interrupts shortly. I've never experienced this with Apple Music.

Comment: Apple is very good at keeping this kind of thing under wraps so who knows. Certainly they have been caught out before, such as when it was discovered that their own apps were allowed to bypass the firewall in Big Sur and were forced to change it

Comment: @Tetsujin: Right, so they advertised a major security flaw well in advance? Plus those security researchers bringing it to light were just wrong? Like Patrick Wardle : `Unfortunately, Apple (without telling anybody) decided to "exclude" or exempt over 50 of its own applications (such as the App Store) and daemons from being routed thru the Network Extension Framework. `

Comment: @JamesP - there we go. Answer to the question as asked. Next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing privilege with priority. Privilege is what allows an app to run at all; priority is how much 'favour' it gets against other apps when the computer is busy.

tbh, this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - thinking up a wild theory as to the cause of a problem then looking for how to fix that, rather than trying to find the actual root of the issue.

Conspiracy theories aside, you can check an app's priority - it's `nice` value - using Activity monitor to quickly get the app's PID, then Terminal to show the current value.
Doing that for iTunes [I don't have Music, my OS is older] & Spotify gives…

```
$ ps -fl -C 92258 [iTunes]
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY       TIME CMD                     F PRI NI       SZ    RSS WCHAN S ADDR
  501 92258     1   0  3:42pm ??     0:02.78 /Applications/iT     4084  61  0  7950436 286104 -     S    0
$ ps -fl -C 92263 [Spotify]
  501 92263     1   0  3:42pm ??     0:05.68 /Applications/Sp     40c4  46  0  7018612 188432 -     S    0
```

So, both have the same priority, zero - which is what most user-facing processes have.
Therefore you should look elsewhere as to why Spotify is buffering. I'd look at your network/router first.